# How to set x value from another cell in a predefined formula using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have this formula (0.01*((x-18)^2)) in one cell (say E3). But the requirement is to get the value of x from A2 to A25, and the calculated value should be displayed in B2 to B25 correspondingly. So please do help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could just change "x" to A2 for example, and then put the (0.01*((A2-18)^2)) in cell B2, and then drag B2 down to B25, and it should replace B2 with B3, B4, ..., B25 so that you have what you're looking for. Hope this helps